# Update capabilities for out-of-the-box default drivers supported by Capybara?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

In Capybara, I can just set a driver like this and execute tests easily:

`Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless`

However I need to update some capabilities, namely one that allows me to set the download path for chromedriver.

Is there a way to just update the default driver with capabilities? I'm looking to keep things easy without having to go through an entire thing with `Capybara.register_driver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn’t, but it’s easy enough to just copy Capybaras registration into your project, modify it, and it will overwrite Capybaras registration

Comment: Okay no problemo. I see the defaults in `/lib/capybara/registrations/drivers.rb` so I'll start with those and add new capabilities I'm looking for.